# spring tests with mocks and HttpMessageConversionException

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, mockito

i have something like that in my ParkingServiceController.

```
@PostMapping("/departure")
public ResponseEntity<String> departure(@RequestBody CarAtGateModel carAtGateModel) throws UnidentifiedCarException {
    CarAndParkingEntity carAndParkingEntity = carsAndParkingsRepository.findByIdCar(
            carAtGateModel.getCarEntity().getIdCar()).orElseThrow(() -> new UnidentifiedCarException());

    carAndParkingEntity.setIdParking("-1");
    carsAndParkingsRepository.flush();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responsesMessages.gateUp(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and next i wanted to do test with some mocks.

```
@Test
public void testArrivalWhenParkingIdNotExists() {
    //given
    CarAndParkingEntity carAndParkingEntity = mock(CarAndParkingEntity.class);
    carAtGateModel = mock(CarAtGateModel.class);
    //when
    when(carsAndParkingsRepository.findByIdCar(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(carAndParkingEntity));
    HttpEntity<CarAtGateModel> request = new HttpEntity<>(carAtGateModel);
    ResponseEntity response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/departure", request, String.class);

    //then
    assertEquals("Parking with that id does not exists", response.getBody());
}
```

but i'm getting that exception every time with every code change in test

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyCrossClassLoaderSerializationSupport]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyCrossClassLoaderSerializationSupport and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.parkingservice.models.CarAtGateModel$MockitoMock$1316802841["mockitoInterceptor"]->org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor["serializationSupport"])
```

When i'm not using any mock test passess correctly so imo i'm doing something wrong with mocking

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, as your ParkingServiceController has a composition with CarsAndParkingRepository, you should mock that dependency first. I don't know why you are mocking carAtGateModel, you can use a real object representing the the data you want to pass to the controller (the same applies to carAndParkingEntity).

It would be helpful if you add more details, explaining what you want to test because it's not totally clear the assertion you are doing.